# Write file from GCP Cloud Function to Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am having a very difficult time simply writing a file from a Cloud Function to a Bucket.

I am using this Medium post: https://medium.com/@Tim_Ebbers/import-a-file-to-gcp-cloud-storage-using-cloud-functions-9cf81db353dc

This is the code of the Cloud Function:

```
#Create function that is triggered by http request
def importFile(request):
    
    #import libraries
    from google.cloud import storage
    from urllib import request

    #set storage client
    client2 = storage.Client()

    # get bucket
    bucket = client2.get_bucket('YOUR-TEST-BUCKET') #without gs://
    blob = bucket.blob('animals-1.json')

    #See if json exists
    if blob.exists() == False :

        #copy file to google storage
        try:
            ftpfile = request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/animals-1.json')
            #for non public ftp file: ftpfile = request.urlopen('ftp://account:password@ftp.domain.com/folder/file.json')
            blob.upload_from_file(ftpfile)
            print('copied animals-1.json to google storage')
        
        #print error if file doesn't exists
        except:
        
            print('animals-1.json does not exist')

    #print error if file already exists in google storage
    else:

        print('file already exists in google storage')
```

The function deploys successfully. When I go to "Test" it, I get the very unhelpful error:

```
Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

**and**

**Logs: Not Available**

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code crashed. This could be a permissions error that thew an exception, code mistake, etc. Add exception handling and logging to your code.

Comment: Yes it was permissions. I assumed (wrongly) that the service account in the same project as the bucket would automatically have write access. It does not. If I give the service account write priv then it works.